# Continous vertical scroller/slideshow, which langague does the trick?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

First off, I don't have any knowledge about java/jquery/ajax or such, but I think I'm looking for a script in one of those languages, I think..

I want a vertical image slideshow or scroller that is 500px in height, 350px and scroll images vertically. Something like this: http://home.comcast.net/~jscheuer1/side/marquee_v_slide.htm

Unfortunately that script is not continous and the whole frame is set to be the same size as the images. I'd like 4-5 images to be shown at the same time, and I've looked everywhere. I hope someone can help me a little :)

I know I'm such a d*ck who wants someone to do all the "job" for me, but I've searched everywhere and I can't find anything that helps me to figure it out. Usually I know enough to customize scripts and learn a lot from it, but I don't know how to write functions in javascripts.. I always mess them up somehow.. :(

Comment: What wasn't continuous about that example? By "4-5 images shown at the same time," do you mean next to each other, slot machine style, or 4-5 images stacked vertically, as they *scroll* vertically (so, basically, if the images are 500px tall, the div itself would be, like, 2500px)?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc I'd like the whole frame to be 500px in height and 350px wide. Inside this frame I want pictures (~100px*300px) to scroll one by one from bottom til' the top. I'd like to divide these images into 2 groups which hopefully can make this script continous without stopping. I also want the images to scroll smootly with the same speed the whole time and not accelerate into focus. I'd would also be a blast if it was possible to slow the script down on mouseover. Does that require a lot of code?

Comment: @jaoza-media The fact that its it can be done in JavaScript or any language, you atleast need to try, you cannot ask anyone here to write a code for you. No one can do the job for you, unless you try and then ask us to debug small issues. Its not a huge piece of cake, give a try. A programmer has to have the learning capabilities

Comment: @Nagaraj Tantri Thank you for your answer. I don't really want anyone to make the script for me, I'm just writing what I want to "create" and then someone can help me in the right direction. As I wrote I've searched everywhere (it feels like that anyway) and I can't find a site which handles the documentation that I need. Maybe your could tell which java functions I need to work with, that would be totally awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can just visit this site http://www.dynamicdrive.com you may find some help. Search for specific scroller's.

Update: your query can been seen with http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/reelslideshow.htm

Comment: I'm sorry but the script doesn't work for me :( The thing is that I've posted another question earlier today about a script I want to fix, but people have stopped posted in it, so I posted this question just to see if there were other options than my current script. But it looks like it's javascript that gets the job done.

Comment: @Jaoza - The thing is, this script is correct. May be you might have got small errors regarding the name or id and hence not getting the script running? Just go through it correctly, because i cannot tell where you are going wrong unless i see the code.!!